# How to make ng-model work in ng-if?

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, dropdown, angular-ng-if

I need to hide and show the div on change of select box, which is already inside ng-if. Here is the code. Please help me.

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <select name="" id="print-type" class="form-control" ng-model="printType">
        <option value="selectOne" selected>Select One</option>
        <option value="selectTwo">Wall Decoration</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6" ng-if="printType == 'selectTwo'">
     <select name="" id="wall-decoration" class="form-control" ng-model="wallDecorDropdown">
          <option value="One">Select One</option>
          <option value="two">Framed Print</option>
     </select>
</div>

<div ng-if="wallDecorDropdown == 'two'">Hi</div>
```

Thanks Very Much.

Comment: Thanks. I need to keep that ng-if because I am hiding and showing it with another select box. Let me edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are breaking the golden rule of always using an object in `ng-model`

The problem is that `ng-if` creates a child scope. So when you change a primitive inside that child scope `ng-model="wallDecorDropdown"` it is hidden from the parent scope since primitives don't have inheritance the same way objects/arrays do

Change to:

```
<div class="col-sm-6" ng-if="printType == 'wallDecor'">
     <select name="" id="wall-decoration" class="form-control" ng-model="myScopeModel.wallDecorDropdown">
          <option value="One">Select One</option>
          <option value="two">Framed Print</option>
     </select>
</div>

<div ng-if="myScopeModel.wallDecorDropdown == 'two'">Hi</div>
```

And in controller create an object that will be inherited by all child scopes

```
$scope.myScopeModel ={}
```

[This 3 minute Egghead video](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-the-dot) is well worth watching to understand better.

Comment: Thanks Very much. Can you please do a codepen for me.

Comment: Hey I have one more Question. How to hide "<div ng-if="myScopeModel.wallDecorDropdown == 'two'">Hi</div>" when this is is selected "<option value="selectTwo">Wall Decoration</option>" Please see updated question

Comment: not clear what you want. Start a new question and include demo as well